# ipywidgets doesn't show plot before interaction

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

Unless the user interacts with widget, ipywidgets doesn't show the plot. How can I solve this? Perhaps if I could update a slider value using some code, the plot would show. I think this issue only arises when the Layout configuration method is used.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interactive, fixed, FloatSlider, HBox, Layout
from IPython.display import display

ts = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)

def plotFunc(omega):
    plt.plot(ts, np.cos(omega*ts))

w = interactive(plotFunc, omega = FloatSlider(min = 0, max = 12, step = 1, value = 6, orientation = 'vertical'))
box_layout = Layout(display = 'flex', flex_flow = 'row', justify_content = 'center', align_items = 'center')
display(HBox([w.children[-1], w.children[0]], layout = box_layout))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable the inline backend for usage with the IPython Notebook:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

and this at the end of your code:

```
w.update()
```

There is some explanation here:

[`%matplotlib inline` commands IPython Documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-matplotlib),

also [`IPython.display.set_matplotlib_formats`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.set_matplotlib_formats) and [`IPython.display.set_matplotlib_close`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.set_matplotlib_close) for more information on changing additional behaviors of the inline backend.

Comment: It works thanks. I just don't know why `%matplotlib inline` is necessary. Without it, it wouldn't work though.

Comment: Guys, I am trying to show the go.Sankey() using the widgets.Output(), the plot is not showing up. Other plots that use the matplotlib show up normally, but this one does not. Do you know any post that can help me to figure out the problem?